# Woocommerce issue with hebrew - shipping methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hebrew, non-english

The issue is on the Additional Rates on shipping flat rate method.

I added some additional rates as it suppose to be, and its display well, but i get "invalid shipping method" when i clicking on the button to continue the process of buying.

the way to add additional rate is:

> description | price | per cost type (order...)

when i am doing it on English, it works perfect, but other languages like Hebrew - i got error of invalid shipping method.

> plugin Version 2.0.20

i cant update the Woocommerce plugin because someone did customization to the site on woo files.

Comment: As a side note, WooCommerce offers customisation much like child themes, I'd investigate that as not being able to update or upgrade your store is potentially vulnerable to attack.

Comment: I agree, thats something that not in my hands... i just try to fix the issue i asked on question

Comment: Fair play, just want to make sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it finally by this:
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/shipping-method-api/

This doc helped me and now it works like a charm.